# How to change the execution time of an infinite animation(in CSS3) smoothly with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have searched through a lot of questions related to my question in stackoverflow but i haven't found one yet that answers my question with plain JavaScript (not using libraries of any kind).

My problem is that I have an infinite animation with CSS3 i.e.:

```
.clockwiseAnimation {
    top: 270px;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-animation: clockwise 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
    -moz-animation: clockwise 4s linear infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
    -o-animation: clockwise 4s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: clockwise 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Safari 5 */
}
@-webkit-keyframes clockwise {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes clockwise {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes clockwise {
    from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes clockwise {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

This animation allows me to spin (clockwise) whatever tag that has the class "clockwiseAnimation".

What I want to do is to change the time of execution (I'll call it speed) of the animation with javascript like:

HTML:

```
<span id="someID" class="clockwiseAnimation">sometext</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var style = document.getElementById("someID").style,
speed = 6; 
//obviously the speed is dynamic within my site (through an `<input type="range">`)
//for the purposes of this example I set the speed to a different value(6seconds) than the original value(4seconds).
style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";
```

It works when I pause and then play(by play I mean UNPAUSE not restart) the animation, i.e.:

```
var style = document.getElementById("someID").style;
some = 6; //it is dynamic (as I pointed out before)

//pause
style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "paused";

//change speed
style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = speed + "s";  

//play (== UNPAUSE) //UPDATE: Added the timeout because I can't get it to work any other way.
setTimeout(function(){
            style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "running";
        },1);
```

UPDATED:

And it works! **BUT**, it has a big RANDOM jump in the animation, meaning that when I change the "speed" with the "`<input type="range">` slider" the element jumps to a random location (not the beginning nor the end of the animation just a random location).

NOTE: Pause and play works very smooth without changing the "speed" of the animation.

**My question(s):** Can I change the "speed" of the animation smoothly **WITH JavaScript**? (WITHOUT the jumping) 
If the answer is: "There is not a way to do it smoothly throughout the animation execution", then:
Is there a way to change it in the next iteration of the **infinite** animation? 
If so: 
Then how can I tell it to start in the next iteration and how to know which is the next iteration if I set the animation to infinite (animation-iteration-count property of the element that is doing the animation always returns "infinite").

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/75rdL/) is an example.** I hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe easing functions will do what you want: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/easing_functions_css3.htm

Comment: That tutorial allowed me to understand MORE about the animations but what I'm trying to do is changing them through js without jumping through points in the animation when modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

What may be occurring is that the `animation-duration` "change" could be "jumping" to the point in the `animation` corresponding to the "changed" `@keyframes` - based on the total "changed" animation duration..

If the `animation-duration` began `from` (or `0%`) proceeded to `to` (or `100%`), the corresponding `@keyframes` "position" may be changed as well.

For example if the original `animation-duration` was `4s` (or, `4000ms`) at approximately `2s` (or, `2000ms`), the corresponding `keyframes` may be at approximately `50%`, or

at 2 seconds into 4 second animation
`50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-180deg); }`

when the `animation-duration` is dynamically changed, the corresponding `keyframes` may be "changed" to the matching `%` point, or, a larger duration span for the same effect. The animated element may *appear* to go forwards or backwards, or hve a "jumping" due to it re-positioning itself within the "changed" corresponding `keyframes` and `animations`.

There is also `1s` `setTimeout` function, that may or may not actually have a `1s` duration.

It may be possible to "smoothly" "jump" to the newly "changed" position within the lengthier `animation-duration` the suggested `transition` effect or `requestAnimationFrame` (http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/).

..

Try this:

html

```
<input type="range" id="speedSlider" min="2000" max="6000" value="4000">
```

css

```
    input {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  
    top : 50px;
    position : absolute;
}

.clockwiseAnimation {
 /* top: 270px;
    left: 200px; */
    left : 50%;
    top : 50%;
    position:absolute;

   /* css animation (no change) */
}
```

js

```
var speedSlider = document.getElementById("speedSlider");
    speedSlider.addEventListener("change", changeSpeed, false);
    function changeSpeed(e){
        var speed = Math.floor(speedSlider.value);
        var element = document.getElementById("span");
        var style = element.style;
        style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        style.webkitAnimationDuration = style.mozAnimationDuration = style.oAnimationDuration = style.animationDuration = String(speed) + "ms";
            style.webkitAnimationPlayState = style.mozAnimationPlayState = style.oAnimationPlayState = style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS: http://jsbin.com/UsunIMa/1/

CSS properties transition and animation allow you to pick the easing function.

```
div {
  transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); 
  /* or */
  animation: clockwise 4s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) infinite;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would allow me to set the cubic bezier function as I would like to, but it will still jump when I dynamically change the c-bezier function.

Comment: what are you trying to achive? I don't get it

Comment: I added an example for you to be able to visualize what I'm trying to accomplish.

I also updated the question, let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout to add animation class to your required element with the removal of animation class as a callback.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how that might be done?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe jQuery `queue` could help you.

[Here it is](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: I didn't want to use any libraries yet, but I will give that a try.

Comment: How exactly would you use the queue to help with the OP's problem?